# pointer use in a function without address

Tags: c++, matlab, pointers

I'm going to try to be as clear as possible, but, I do apologize if I end up not being. I've been working on this for a while now and I'm pretty new to c++.

**Edit 2: cObj is a class object defined in another file**

I've been writing some wrapper code in matlab, and implementation code in c++. Some of my code uses pointers as arguments to a function, whose only purpose is to be a c interface to a c++ function. The c interface function looks like below, as an example.

```
DLLEXPORT int GetInfo(int num, int* ChannelMask, int* ChannelIndex)
{
    return cObj->GetChannelInfo(num, ChannelMask, ChannelIndex);
}
```

Now here's where I have the question, and I will provide more code to illustrate.

The function GetChannelInfo also takes pointer arguments, in fact, the exact same pointer arguments as in GetInfo.

So it looks like this.

```
int CCan::GetChannelInfo(int num, int* ChannelMask, int* ChannelIndex)
{
    unsigned char* pChanIndex = &ChanIndex //Class variable
    unsigned long long pChanMaskTx = &ChanMaskTx; //Also a class variable

    *pChanMaskTx = Some Assignment value, lets say 5;
    *pChanIndex = Another assignment value, let's say 6; //just for arguments sake, don't care about the type.

    //Now this is passed to the original pointer value
    *ChannelMask = *pChanMaskTx;
    *ChannelIndex = *pChanIndex;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is this, in the first function GetInfo, why is it okay, or even legal to pass the num, ChannelMask, and ChannelIndex the way it does.
i.e. return cObj->GetChannelInfo(num, ChannelMask, ChannelIndex);

Generally, when I see pointers in articles on the internet, it's something like this.

```
void func(int* B)
{
    *B = *B + 1;
}

int main ()
{
   int A = 5;
   func(&A);
   //Now A is equal to 6 instead of 5
}
```

What happened to the address being passed? In the functions I've written (which I have done based off a coworkers code), it does seem to work. But, I am beyond confused as to why, or how it works. As I understood it, a pointer needs an address at some point. But, nowhere in my code did that happen. I'm hoping somebody could shed some light on this, and what's going on. Or maybe I'm doing it completely wrong, and by sheer accident it's appears to be working.

**Edit 1: num was not supposed to be a pointer. The crux of the question is in the DLLEXPORT part by the way. And GetChannelInfo is a member of a class. I instantiated cObj as a pointer object at the top of the code where GetInfo is defined**

**Edit 3: Why am I getting downvoted? I thought this was where you come to ask questions when you don't know/have the answer, especially when you're new. Have you all been programming so long you forgot what it's like to not know? Sheesh..**

**ANSWER**

**Edit 4: I'm going to provide a little bit more detail in case somebody else runs into this. The accepted answer explains it well. What I didn't include in my original question is the matlab code, which might be something to the effect of:**

```
function [status] = GetChannelInfo(num)
    status = calllib('Test','GetInfo',num, 0,0);
```

**What's happening above in the calllib function (which we don't see) is that matlab passes the address of the last two arguments in calllib to the calling function, which I would have had to do in c or c++ if I was writing the entire thing in c or c++.**

Comment: You really should recap the `&` operator! (and possibly pointers in general)

Comment: As written, it's not legal, because you have mismatched indirection on `num` (one pointer, one plain `int`)

Comment: Why are people downvoting this - obviously a new programmer - which is not a crime!

Comment: @Olaf, hence why I posted the question. I am fairly new to c++, lots of matlab programming, but that's not really programming, more scripting I guess. I know the & operator allows you to assign address to a pointer, essentially, thus, allowing the pointer to modify the variable it points to by dereferencing it with *. Did I miss anything? Where I start to get confused when there is more than simple define pointer, assign pointer another variables address, then modify it.

Comment: This is C++ code, so please remove the 'c' tag.

Comment: these two lines (I haven't checked all the other lines) are not correct: `unsigned char* pChanIndex = &ChanIndex 
    unsigned long long pChanMaskTx = &ChanMaskTx; `  the first line is taking the address of an address, but the type 'unsigned char *' only has one '*' instead of two '**'.   the second line is taking the addres of an address, but the type 'unsigned long long' is not a pointer at all.   When compiling, always enable all warnings, then fix those warnings (and both these lines will output compiler warnings.) (for g++, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: continued: on those same two lines, the compiler will also output warnings about changing the type from 'int *' to unsigned long long int * and 'int *' to 'unsigned char'

Comment: Your getting less than positive votes because it is obvious that you have not properly compiled the posted code.

Comment: I have compiled the code. I have simply posted a snippet of what I have, made mistakes when copying and modifying for the question. I didn't want to include 30 lines of code, so I tried to pull out my specific question from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific question was why it's legal to pass `ChannelMask` to a function which requires a pointer. As an answer, consider this

```
void bar(int *ptr) {
    // ... 
}

void foo(int *ptr) {
    bar(ptr);
}

int main(void) {
    int x;
    foo(&x);
}
```

You can see that `foo` and `bar` both require a pointer. `main` passes the address of `x` to `foo`, because `x` is not a pointer. Then `foo` passes `ptr` to `bar`, because `ptr` is already a pointer.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening. Thank you for the clear answer. I appreciate that you answered the question instead of telling me I'm new.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - seems a bad example anyway

cObj looks like some global which you do not show
GetChannelInfo is not a member function of a class

Function signatures do not match
int GetInfo(int* num, int* ChannelMask, int* ChannelIndex)
int GetChannelInfo(int num, int* ChannelMask, int* ChannelIndex)

ie num is a pointer in one but not the other

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code - can you post a full example

Comment: I edited the question with a few corrections and a little extra detail. I can provide the original class, or at least a snippet if necessary.